# How to organizing controllers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a question about how to organizing controllers in ASP.NET MVC.
For example, say that you have a database table for Contacts and one for Activities.
The activity table has a foreign key to ContactId, so you must add a activity to an existing contact.

Now in ASP.NET MVC. Should the Contact controller also handle activities actions?
Or should i create a ActivityController and have Add, Edit, Delete in this?

The process may vary, but are there any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends whether Activities and Contacts can be separated from one another or do they have to be treated as one. You normally want to follow Single Responsibility Principle. Basically, your controller should have one duty and each action should do one specific operation. For example, you might have `ContactsController`. The controller has one responsibility and that is to manipulate one type of object, Contacts in this case. As part of this manipulation you will have actions which accomodate this by having each one of them performs certain CRUD operation.

On the other hand you have `Activities` for each `Contact`. What you plan to do with Activities and how you plan to treat them is entirely up to you. Is it necessary to list every registered activity for every contact? If yes implement it as an ActivitiesController which has its own CRUD operations. Some of the actions in this controller will receive contact ID to help assign activity to contact, etc.

If the answer to the previous question is no and you do not need to treat activities as a separate process, then see to integrate it somehow into contacts, but to be honest, I would still go on with the separation of the two. Think a bit into the future if requirements change and you realize that Activities must be a separate process. If you tightly integrated two models, you will have hard time separating them (OK, probably not that hard, but it would be pain in the neck). If you separate them now it will be easier to maintain them in the long run. In addition to all this, separating the two will help you create controllers which are more lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

It is really down to how you are building your screens.

I don't know how you are building your screens but say I had an edit contact page, and part of that page displayed the list of activities and then allowed you to add/edit/delete activities. I would use Ajax to handle this and then create an Activity WebApi controller (if you are using MVC4) to handle the Ajax calls.

If you are using MVC3 then I would add the methods to the Contact controller.

EDIT:

In support of @Husein who presented his case much better than I did - it is definitely about how you want to deal with the object graph. My description above makes the assumption that you are not dealing with activities in isolation - they are dealt with only as part of a Contact object.